# Toggle button inside angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

In my angular reactive form i am trying to use **three state toggle switch** for which i have tried three state switch separately in the link

**Three state toggle stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation-gh1dj1

And i need to implement the same with same css inside **reactive form** on each row inside formarray.

For which i have tried the same html and css and given as `formcontrolname` like,

```
      <div class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
<ng-container #buttonIcon *ngFor="let option of options" >
  <input type="radio" formControlName="state" [checked]="value === option"
               [value]="option" />
        <label (click)="onSelectionChange(option)"  for="{{option}}">{{option.id}}
        </label></ng-container> <a></a>
          </div>
```

But i couldn't achieve the result.

**Reactive form stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-yqraay

Please click over the add button in the second stackblitz to see the result.. Added the css in `app.component.css`..

Kindly help me to implement the three state toggle switch as like in the first stackblitz into the reactive form in second stackblitz and need to get the values of selected toggle..

Comment: I'm already looking into it. Your three-way switch doesn't seem to work in the Reactive Forms.

Comment: Yes you are correct  its not working inside reactive form.. Kindly help me in it please to include the three state switch inside reactive form..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `[id]` to the input tag and an `[attr.for]` to the label tag. Something like this:

```
<div 
  class="switch-toggle switch-3 switch-candy">
  <ng-container 
    #buttonIcon 
    *ngFor="let option of options">
    <input 
      type="radio" 
      formControlName="state" 
      [value]="option" 
      [id]="i+option" />
    <label 
      [attr.for]="i+option">
      {{option}}
    </label>
  </ng-container>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disable-group-control-value-on-another-control-value-for-smok31?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

---

Thanks to A.Winnen for his comments on the performance implications of using the previous approach.

Comment: Sorry for missing one thing.. In default na needs to be as selected for all the rows..

Comment: Just add `state: 'na'` in your `addCreds` method when you push a new `FormGroup`

Comment: I am able to check in mobile only now so as of i have seen there is no issue with what i am in need.. I will accept your answer if any queries will let you know..

Comment: @undefined, no issues. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @SiddAjmera, Each time I see a (ngModelChange) in a ReactiveForm I go to crazy :)

Comment: Kindly check for the toggle buttons if i click over the second row or anything then the first toggle button alone getting changes not what we change.. Please check the  stackblitz you provided..

Comment: @SiddAjmera, I think you have changed your previous stackblitz and i am suffering from getting the expected output of toggle switch in all the rows separately..

Comment: @undefined, you can actually get rid of the methods that we created earlier and use this approach instead.

Comment: @SiddAjmera, Thats fine but why toggle switch not working for others rows except first??

Comment: @SiddAjmera, PLease switch the toggle in second or third row you will see the changes will happen only in first row toggle.. I think something was missed.. When you give first solution it was working earlier now the changed one not working..

Comment: @undefined, I think it should work now. I forgot to add the index of the FormGroup on `input`'s `name` and `label`'s `for` attributes. That's why it was taking the same name for each input field. It should work now. Updated the stackblitz as well.

Answer (score 1):

The options array in your reactive component is different than the 3 way switch you implemented. The one in the real component does not have the `id`.

```
[
  "on",
  "na",
  "off"
]
```

You can still use that like this:

```
<ng-container #buttonIcon *ngFor="let option of options" >
  <input type="radio" formControlName="state" [checked]="value === option"
               [value]="option" />
        <label (click)="onSelectionChange(option)"  for="{{option}}"> 
            {{option}} //**refer the object as the id filed is missing**
        </label>
```

Second difference is, you are missing the `onSelectionChange` function in your reactive component

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stackblitz demo for your referance.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szsw3k